# Mongoose.js: Find user by username LIKE value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, find, mongoose

I like to to go find a user in mongoDb by looking for a user called value.
The problem with:

```
username: 'peter'
```

is that i dont find it if the username is "Peter", or "PeTER".. or something like that.

So i want to do like sql

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE 'peter'
```

Hope you guys get what im askin for?

*Short: 'field LIKE value' in mongoose.js/mongodb*

Comment: Just an aside, the SQL query wouldn't find `Peter` or `PeTER` either as `LIKE` is not case-insensitive.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

For those that were looking for a solution here it is:

```
var name = 'Peter';
model.findOne({name: new RegExp('^'+name+'$', "i")}, function(err, doc) {
  //Do your action here..
});
```

Comment: what does "i" argument mean? Does it have anything to do with case sensitivity?

Comment: "i" is an argument for choosing a searching flag. "i" then is for case-insensitive. You can read more about it here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: This assumes the regex isn't invalid. If you add "[" as a username for example, will throw exception. Just ensure you are either try-catching or regexing your input prior and checking for [^a-zA-Z0-9] then not proceeding. In this case, its just test input so makes sense.

Comment: $ = Match the end of the string

Comment: @JasonSebring Although I agree that input validation is not a bad idea, the best approach is an actual escaping algorithm. And exceptions are not even the worst problem, but imagine you used similar code on a login page and a user entered `".*"` as the username.

Comment: @still_learning true. Do you know of one for this issue? I haven't thought much about it but it is necessary.

Comment: @still_learning found it here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex

Comment: {[nameOFFieldHere]: new RegExp([charSetForFindHere], "i")} This is a little bit improved string literal handling with [ ] and in new RegExp ( ) , it automatically added /charSetForFindHere/ pattern with / and / , which comes from inbuilt regex eg: {"firstName": /Bri/} Therefore use above like : {[fieldnameVariable]: new RegExp([searchStringChars], "i")} with variable field name and variable char set.

Answer (score 83):

I had problems with this recently, i use this code and work fine for me.

```
var data = 'Peter';

db.User.find({'name' : new RegExp(data, 'i')}, function(err, docs){
    cb(docs);
});
```

Use directly `/Peter/i` work, but i use `'/'+data+'/i'` and not work for me.

Comment: Well, i just tried it some more.

I see it also find if i just write P?? hmmm.

Comment: Yes, i use for ajax petitions to search users. You can modify the RegExp.

Answer (score 42):

```
db.users.find( { 'username' : { '$regex' : req.body.keyWord, '$options' : 'i' } } )
```

Comment: @MikeShi What is an example scenario of this?

Comment: @LenJoseph just in general the ReDoS attack: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Regular_expression_Denial_of_Service_-_ReDoS, I'm unaware if mongoose is vulnerable at this point, or if there is any intended functionality to detect ReDoS inputs and sanitize them at the mongoose level.

Answer (score 16):

```
collection.findOne({
    username: /peter/i
}, function (err, user) {
    assert(/peter/i.test(user.username))
})
```

Comment: what if the value is a var? How to set that up? /varhere/i ?

Comment: @PeterBechP construct a regular expression :\ `new RegExp(var, "i")`

Comment: works fine.. now i got a problem.. It only have to find peter if the var is peter. But if i set the var to 'p' it will still find peter.

Comment: @PeterBechP  then remove the case insensitivity flag :\

Answer (score 15):

```
router.route('/product/name/:name')
.get(function(req, res) {

    var regex = new RegExp(req.params.name, "i")
    ,   query = { description: regex };

    Product.find(query, function(err, products) {
        if (err) {
            res.json(err);
        }

        res.json(products);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 13):

You should use a regex for that.

```
db.users.find({name: /peter/i});
```

Be wary, though, that this query doesn't use index.

Answer (score 9):

mongoose doc for find.
mongodb doc for regex.

```
var Person = mongoose.model('Person', yourSchema);
// find each person with a name contains 'Ghost'
Person.findOne({ "name" : { $regex: /Ghost/, $options: 'i' } },
    function (err, person) {
             if (err) return handleError(err);
             console.log('%s %s is a %s.', person.name.first, person.name.last, person.occupation);
});
```

Note the first argument we pass to `mongoose.findOne` function: `{ "name" : { $regex: /Ghost/, $options: 'i' } }`, `"name"` is the field of the document you are searching, `"Ghost"` is the regular expression, `"i"` is for case insensitive match. Hope this will help you.

Comment: what are the $options

Answer (score 9):

The following query will find the documents with required string ***case insensitively         and with global occurrence also***

```
var name = 'Peter';
    db.User.find({name:{
                         $regex: new RegExp(name, "ig")
                     }
                },function(err, doc) {
                                     //Your code here...
              });
```

Answer (score 9):

This is what I'm using.

```
module.exports.getBookByName = function(name,callback){
    var query = {
            name: {$regex : name}
    }
    User.find(query,callback);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here my code with expressJS:

```
router.route('/wordslike/:word')
    .get(function(request, response) {
            var word = request.params.word;       
            Word.find({'sentence' : new RegExp(word, 'i')}, function(err, words){
               if (err) {response.send(err);}
               response.json(words);
            });
         });
```

Answer (score 2):

Just complementing @PeterBechP 's answer.

**Don't forget to scape the special chars.**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6969486

```
function escapeRegExp(string) {
  return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
}

var name = 'Peter+with+special+chars';

model.findOne({name: new RegExp('^'+escapeRegExp(name)+'$', "i")}, function(err, doc) {
  //Do your action here..
});
```

Answer (score 2):

For dynamic search, you can follow like this also,

```
const { keyword, skip, limit, sort } = pagination(params);
const search = keyword
      ? {
          title: {
            $regex: new RegExp(keyword, 'i')
          }
        }
      : {};

Model.find(search)
      .sort(sort)
      .skip(skip)
      .limit(limit);
```

Answer (score 1):

if I want to query all record at some condition，I can use this:

```
if (userId == 'admin')
  userId = {'$regex': '.*.*'};
User.where('status', 1).where('creator', userId);
```

Comment: Seems like an unnecessary use of `$regex` when you could have just used `{ $exists: true }`.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution for converting **every value** in a **req.body** to a mongoose *LIKE* param:

```
let superQ = {}

Object.entries({...req.body}).map((val, i, arr) => {
    superQ[val[0]] = { '$regex': val[1], '$options': 'i' }
})

User.find(superQ)
  .then(result => {
    res.send(result)})
  .catch(err => { 
    res.status(404).send({ msg: err }) })
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var name = 'Peter';

model.findOne({
  name: {
    $regex: name,
    $options: 'i'
  }, 
  function(err, doc) {
  //your logic
});
```

for more information you can refer this link https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/