# How to find items using regex in Mongoose

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongoose

In Mongoose doc I didn't find an equivalent for [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) of MongoDb. Can you provide a simple Mongoose `find()` with a regex expression?

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824010/mongoose-js-find-user-by-username-like-value answers your question (quick Google search)? `db.users.find({name: /peter/i});`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you are right. It helped. This one is good: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24791882/1075289

Answer (score 79, accepted):

mongoose [doc for find](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html).

mongodb [doc for regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/).

```
   var Person = mongoose.model('Person', yourSchema);
   // find each person with a name contains 'Ghost'
   Person.findOne({ "name" : { $regex: /Ghost/, $options: 'i' } },
          function (err, person) {
                 if (err) return handleError(err);
                 console.log('%s %s is a %s.', person.name.first, person.name.last, person.occupation);

   });
```

Note the first argument we pass to mongoose.findOne function. "{ "name" : { $regex: /Ghost/, $options: 'i' } }". "name" is the field of the document you are searching. "Ghost" is the regular expression. "i" is for case insensitive match. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks - this was helpful - just one thing... if you have a variable seems that you don't need to include the '/'.  just {$regex:myVar, $options:'I'}}.  Adding the '/' either before the variable name or concatenating them did not work for me.