# Like filter with mongoose-paginate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to make pagination on Node.js, but mongoose with mongoose-paginate not works with like expressions.

I have found [Mongoose.js: Find user by username LIKE value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824010/mongoose-js-find-user-by-username-like-value), but result is always empty.

My Entity contains 'target' field. There are entities with 'test' in Entity.target. My code is:

```
 var filter = {};
    if (req.param('filter')) {
        filter = {
            target: new RegExp('^'+'test'+'$', "i")
        }
    }

    var params = {
        page: getPage(req),
        limit: getCount(req)
    };


    Entity.paginate(filter, params, function (err, result) {             
        res.json(result);
    });
```

If I run query in mongo console, I get correct result:

```
{"target":{"$regex":"te","$options":"gi"}}
```

Do you have some ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your filter query to

```
var filter = { "target": {} };
if (req.param('filter')) {
    filter["target"]["$regex"] = new RegExp(req.param('filter'), "i");       
} else {
    filter = { };
}
```