# Mongoose - Is it possible to modify key's value to match with where condition for find() query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle, mongodb, mongoose

I am very familiar with Oracle when suddenly i had to create a project with MongoDB database. I am using mongoose to connect to my MongoDB. My question is, is that possible to match find condition before doing a query? 
For example, i got this `name : John` in my MongoDB then i just need to do this by Oracle SQL.

```html
SELECT * FROM MY_SCHEMA.WORKERS WORKER
WHERE UPPER(WORKER.NAME) = 'JOHN'
```

In mongoDB, all I know and can do is this.

```html
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('localhost:27017/myDB');
workers.find(
  {
    "name": "JOHN"
  }
);
```

I have been searching for solution and can't find one. Is there any way to set `name`'s value to upper case to match the result i needed?

Any help would be appreciated :)

**EDIT :**
I found the solution to this problem by using RegExp() for mongoose. RegExp will make my mongoDB docs case-insensitive to match my query's parameter. More details in this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9824712/7498283

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `toUpperCase()` of javascript, if you want to do find with uppercase letters. [refer-doc](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_touppercase.asp).

Try the code below:

```
workers.find(
{
  "name": ("JOHN").toUpperCase()
});
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: It's the `value` inside my document that I need to upperCase, not the parameter send from my client-side. But, thankyou for your response. :D

Comment: Can you show us your db and what you want to get with your find query?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/kfJp6pgQ for example, i need to get `John` by using `JOHN` as my filter. Thankyou :D

Comment: Please have a look into the answer of the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863399/mongodb-is-it-possible-to-make-a-case-insensitive-query)

Comment: You can also try using  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#op._S_text

Comment: Will it work on mongoose? It works perfectly if i `find()` John from mongo shell. :D

Comment: Try it and let us know.

Comment: your answer works by using RegExp for mongoose. RegExp will make all of my data in mongoDB docs become case insensitive to my query's parameter. More details in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9824712/7498283

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $toUpper operator in mongodb.

```
    worker.aggregate([
           {$project: {"name":{$toUpper:"$name"}}},
           {$find:{"name":"JOHN"}}
    ]);
```

Comment: Sorry, but I am using mongoose to do database CRUD. I edited my post just to point out that. Do you have any solution using mongoose to operate in mongoDB?