# How I can use "LIKE" operator on mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem when i query using mongoose.I coding follow this [Mongoose.js: Find user by username LIKE value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824010/mongoose-js-find-user-by-username-like-value). But it return blank.

This my code return blank.

```
 var promise = UserSchema.find({name: /req.params.keyword/ }).limit(5);
```

I tried this return blank seem.

`var n = john; var promise = UserSchema.find({name: /n/ }).limit(5);`

But i tried this is working

```
 var promise = UserSchema.find({name: /john/ }).limit(5);
```

Why I use variable then return blank?

Comment: The /.../ syntax is only for strings, not variables. Many of the answers in the question you've linked provide your answer.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

use `$regex` in mongodb

[how to use regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)

example

```
select * from table where abc like %v%
```

in mongo

```
 var colName="v";
 models.customer.find({ "abc": { $regex: '.*' + colName + '.*' } },
   function(err,data){
         console.log('data',data);
  });
```

**Your query look like**

```
var name="john";
UserSchema.find({name: { $regex: '.*' + name + '.*' } }).limit(5);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Above find is case-sensitive. how can I do this with case-insensitive?

Comment: Have you read a documentation [how to use regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)?

you need to use `{ <field>: { $regex: 'pattern', $options: '<options>' } }` with options `i`, e.g. `{ name: { $regex: req.params.keyword, $options: 'i' } }`

Comment: `i` is use for case insensitive

Comment: You can add options after the regex pattern as usual. `/pattern/i`

Answer (score 31):

Or just simply

```
const name = "John"
UserSchema.find({name: {$regex: name, $options: 'i'}}).limit(5);
```

**i** for case-insensitive

Answer (score 14):

This is how i have done it to find if search string present in name/email.
Hope it helps someone.

```js
const getPeerSuggestions = async (req, res, next) => {

  const { search } = req.query;
  const rgx = (pattern) => new RegExp(`.*${pattern}.*`);
  const searchRgx = rgx(search);

  const peers = await User.find({
    $or: [
      { name: { $regex: searchRgx, $options: "i" } },
      { email: { $regex: searchRgx, $options: "i" } },
    ],
  })
    .limit(5)
    .catch(next);

  res.json(peers);
};
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use the RegExp object to make a regex with a variable, add the 'i' flag if you want the search to be case insensitive.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = mongoose.model('user');

const userRegex = new RegExp(userNameVariable, 'i')
return User.find({name: userRegex})
```

Answer (score 1):

Without `aggregate` it didn't work for me. But this did:

```
db.dbname.aggregate([{ "$match" : {"name" : { $regex: '.*SERGE.*', $options: 'i' } }}, { $sort: { "createdTime" : -1 }} ]).pretty()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 select * from table where abc like %_keyword%
```

in mongo it is

```
  const list = await ProductModel.find({{ pname :{ $regex : '.*'+ _keyword + '.*' }});
```

here `_keyword` can be any text eg. fruit, pen, etc. as i am searching products model.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a regex lookup with dynamic values using `RegExp`:

```js
 var promise = UserSchema.find({name: new RegExp(req.params.keyword, 'i') }).limit(5);
```

Notice the `'i'` option for case insensitivity.