# how do I use a variable in find() method when looking for similar matches?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I am making a dictionary web app and now I am trying to make a search engine. I want to partly enter a word and get all of the similar matches. For example, I enter "ava", and get "lava" and "available" back. Mongoose has a method to do that but I need to enclose my query into slashes (like this /query/). I can do that with a string but I don't know how to put a variable in there in order to make a user search.

> // executes, name LIKE john and only selecting the "name" and "friends" fields

**await MyModel.find({ name: /john/i }, 'name friends').exec();**

Here's my code:

```
app.post("/search", function(req, res){
  let search = req.body.wordSearch;
  console.log(req.body.wordSearch);
  Dicword.find({word: /search/i}, function(err, searchRes) {
    search = searchRes;
    res.render("search", {search: search});
  } );
})
```

I use **let search** to store the query and a result of a search but when I put it in find method with slashes /search/, it gets recognized as a string and not a variable. How can I use a variable there?

Comment: Have you seen: [How I can use "LIKE" operator on mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43729199)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How I can use "LIKE" operator on mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43729199/how-i-can-use-like-operator-on-mongoose)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

```
{ word: /search/i }
```

Write like this

```
{ word: `/${search}/i` }
```