# MONGOOSE find a document using a string (LIKE %SQL)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I want to find a document using the date field contained in the collection

```
//Document Exemple: MODEL : MY_EVENT

event_time_produce: '2018-01-03T11:00:00.201Z',
event_name : 'show'
```

I would like to find all the documents starting with '2018-01-03T11:00:'

I want to ignore the part of Millesecobde & ISOtype ..etc

Like in SQL :

```
SELECT * from MY_EVENT where event_time_produce LIKE '2018-01-03T11:00:%'
```

I have tried this but not working ( Mongoose)

```
MY_EVENT.find({event_time_produce : {
                        $regex: new RegExp('^2018-01-03T11:00:00.*$')
                    }})
         .exec(....)
```

Simple search work :

```
MY_EVENT.find({event_time_produce : '2018-01-03T11:00:00.201Z'})
         .exec(....)
```

but I want to get all the documents from 03 Janury 2018 at 11:00:XX

no matter the second just verify the date, hours & minute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose.js: Find user by username LIKE value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824010/mongoose-js-find-user-by-username-like-value)

Comment: I have seen this post but not working for me ! may bee the date & time ?

Comment: No, it shouldn't matter. Are you sure you have the dates stored as string in mongodb ?

Comment: the date are stored with type Date !

Comment: that is your problem right there. Change them to strings for regex to work.

Comment: ISODate("2018-01-03T11:00:00.201Z") is the format in MONGOdb !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162531/discussion-between-anis-mokeddes-and-veeram).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it an issue on your regular expression?

On your example for SQL you have `2018-01-03T11:00:%` When on mongo you got `^2018-01-03T11:00:00.*$` (2 additional zeros after `11:00:`)

Update:
If your data on the actual document is ISODate instead of a regular string, better to use ranges like this:
`{event_time_produce:{$gte:ISODate("2018-01-03T11:00:00.000+0000"),$lte:ISODate("2018-01-03T11:00:59.999+0000") }}`

Comment: i searchc a function in Mongoose Like DATEPART() function in SQL !

Comment: SELECT * FROM record 
    WHERE  (DATEPART(yy, register_date) = 2009
    AND    DATEPART(mm, register_date) = 10
    AND    DATEPART(dd, register_date) = 10)

Comment: how about using a range on the date? (updated my answer to reflect that)