# Mongoose search by a property that contain multiple values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Let's say I have two users in my MongoDb (user1 and user2)

```
      {
        UserName : "user1",
        WorkingFor : "Company1"
      }
```

and user2

```
      {
        UserName : "user2",
        WorkingFor : "Company1,Company2"
      }
```

now I want to search users who works for company1 using mongoose so i am using the following query :

```
          Users.find({WorkingFor:"Company1"}).then(foundedUsers =>{
               console.log(foundedUsers); // it will print only user1
           });
```

**Problem : this query will return only user1**  and when i modify it to :

```
      Users.find({WorkingFor:"Company1,Company2"}).then(foundedUsers =>{
               console.log(foundedUsers); // it will print only user2
           });
```

**So what should I modify in my query to let it return user1 and user2 ?**

Comment: Is your document structure unmutable, or can you slightly change it?

Comment: Apparently, you have a bad model structure. Why is `WorkingFor` not an array? In your case, use regexp search.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9932470/4455767

Comment: @Lemix yeah it's working after changing the WorkingFor type in the Schema from String to Array . Thank you !